# How to detect interdependence of functions

Tags: functions, reference-request

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be two functions (assume them to be regular enough, let's say $L^2(\mathbb{R})$). It might be the case that these functions are not totally independent. For example we could have that the value of $f(x)$ depends in some way on the value of $g(x-t)$. How is it possible to detect such interdependences?

A first idea I had was to look at the Fourier transform of the two functions. Then if $f(x)$ depends somewhat strongly (e.g. linearly) on $g(x)$, the transforms should be basically the same except for multiplication by some factor (by the usual Fourier transform of a shifted function rule).

Another thing I found around is [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation), but this does not work well for non-linear phenomena.

Is my first idea viable? And are there good references on the subject around?

Also, what are the correct tags for this question?

Comment: Functional dependence can be found when Jacobian vanishes.

Comment: @Narasimham Sorry, I don't think I understand... Would you care to elaborate, please?

Answer (score -1):

[FunctionalDependence](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~dwm/Courses/1PD/1PD-N3.pdf)

page 17

Criterion for functional independence of $ u(x,y), v(x,y) $ is through the Jacobian

$$ J= \dfrac{\partial (u(x,y),v(x,y))}{\partial (x,y)} \ne 0 $$

In the event of vanishing J, function defining transformation $u$ to $v$ can be also found out.

Comment: Please inform how the reply may be improved.

Comment: The question is about the "interdependence" of two functions of a _single_ variable (i.e. the domain is $\mathbb R$); I believe that $t$ in the question is supposed to be a constant. Moreover, [$L^2$ functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces) are not necessarily differentiable. Your answer, on the other hand, is about differentiable transformations $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ (to emphasize, the domain here is $\mathbb R^2$). I fail to see its relevance.

Comment: There's also the matter of local vs. global. Your answer boils down to the _local_ properties of a transformation, involving differentials and tangent spaces, while the question seems to be about the _global_ correlation between two functions.